# Getting HTTP/0.0 307 Temporary Redirect in connecting to my vps without typing https://

Tags: ssl, https, dns, cloudflare, vps

I ran a graphical version of v2ray([X-UI](https://seakfind.github.io/2021/10/10/X-UI/)) on one of my VPS on Hetzner, I also add an `A` record to bind the IP of this VPS to a DNS on my Cloudflare account.

Well with the below commands, I tried to get a certificate for this subdomain with `acme.sh` and using letsencrypt as CA provider:

```bash
    7  curl https://get.acme.sh | sh
    8  ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --set-default-ca --server letsencrypt
    9  ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --register-account -m myemail@mailserver.com
   10  ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d sub.mydns.com --standalone
   11  ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --installcert -d sub.mydns.com --key-file /root/private.key --fullchain-file /root/cert.crt
```

After adding the IP address of VPS to Cloudflare and setting it in DNS-only mode like the below image:

[image]

When I try to connect my panel without typing the `https://`, I've just got the below page from Firefox:

[image]

And also return nothing in the Google Chrome browser(with or without typing `https://`):

[image]

But typing `https://` shows me the panel successfully:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your question.

##### Thats because HTTPS redirection is not executed automatically by your installed application.

Your application is showing 307 error for http requests without redirecting them automatically. Its a security matter designed by your application to disable http access when you introduce HTTPS certificates in its panel.

Answer (score -1):

Cloudflare does not allow all the ports. so make sure you are using ports that cloudfalre accepts. sth that i tried was using Web socket (ws) with port 2082.
then go to ssl settings on cloud flare and deactivate all. its probably auto redirecting http to https and you are not supporting that.

Comment: I'm not talking about configs in v2ray, this issue is about my admin panel address and I say in my post that I use `dns-only` mode of Cloudflare and what you said is True in `proxy` mode of Cloudflare.